# Running ROSJAVA as a thread in a larger app

Tags: ros, threads, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How might the ROSJAVA talker example be spawned as a separate thread since it must be passed the NodeConfiguration at startup? I get an error stating that I cannot cast my main file to org.ros.node.NodeMain.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11577/running-rosjava-as-a-thread-in-a-larger-app./) by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2011-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out. I have to implement NodeMain in the main java file, save the passed NodeConfiguration to a global volatile, and read it from the runnable() which contains the RosNode. I am sure there is a better way of doing it (such as simply passing the NodeConfiguration to the run() method) but this works for now. If I run into problems with it, I will post an update.

---

Originally posted by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) with karma: 56 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way to run a RosMain instance in a thread is to use the NodeRunner class.

```
NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration =
        NodeConfiguration.newPublic(InetAddressFactory.newNonLoopback().getHostName(),
                getMasterUri());
FooNodeMain foo = new FooNodeMain();
DefaultNodeRunner.newDefault().run(foo, nodeConfiguration);
```

In the above example, the class FooNodeMain needs to implement org.ros.node.NodeMain. NodeRunner's run method is non-blocking and just runs your node in a new thread and you can call it multiple times to spawn different nodes.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1